# Restructure dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, reshape

I want to restructure my pandas dataframe where h1, h2 etc are values associated to the hour. It currently looks like:

```
             h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6    h7    h8    h9  ...    h15  \
 date                                                              ...          

2004-01-01   46  46  45  41  39  35  33.0  33.0  36.0  ...   55.0   
2004-01-02   43  44  46  46  47  47  47.0  47.0  47.0  ...   54.0   
2004-01-03   45  46  46  44  43  46  46.0  47.0  51.0  ...   69.0
```

I want to restructure it to look like:

```
    date         value                                                                      

2004-01-01 1:00    46   
2004-01-01 2:00    46     
2004-01-01 3:00    45
2004-01-01 4:00    41 
2004-01-01 5:00    39 
2004-01-01 6:00    35 
2004-01-01 7:00    33
...  
2004-01-02 1:00    43
2004-01-02 2:00    44
2004-01-02 3:00    46  
...
```

Not certain how to go about this. Any ideas?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that'll get the values but not the date column.  I'm sure it's trivial to get the date with hours without too much trouble, but I'd be more inclined to put in an effort if OP had tried it first.

Comment: @Idlehands Uh, I was browsing on my phone, wanted to help OP out. Turns out I misread the question and could do nothing about it. Well, I've removed my comment, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `stack` then , assign new index

```
s=df.stack()
s.index=pd.to_datetime(s.index.get_level_values(level=0)+' '+s.index.get_level_values(level=1).str[1:].str.pad(2,fillchar='0'),format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
s#s.to_frame('Value').reset_index()

Out[1012]: 
2004-01-01 01:00:00    46.0
2004-01-01 02:00:00    46.0
2004-01-01 03:00:00    45.0
2004-01-01 04:00:00    41.0
2004-01-01 05:00:00    39.0
2004-01-01 06:00:00    35.0
2004-01-01 07:00:00    33.0
2004-01-01 08:00:00    33.0
2004-01-01 09:00:00    36.0
2004-01-02 01:00:00    43.0
2004-01-02 02:00:00    44.0
2004-01-02 03:00:00    46.0
2004-01-02 04:00:00    46.0
2004-01-02 05:00:00    47.0
2004-01-02 06:00:00    47.0
2004-01-02 07:00:00    47.0
2004-01-02 08:00:00    47.0
2004-01-02 09:00:00    47.0
2004-01-03 01:00:00    45.0
2004-01-03 02:00:00    46.0
2004-01-03 03:00:00    46.0
2004-01-03 04:00:00    44.0
2004-01-03 05:00:00    43.0
2004-01-03 06:00:00    46.0
2004-01-03 07:00:00    46.0
2004-01-03 08:00:00    47.0
2004-01-03 09:00:00    51.0
dtype: float64
```